# $F(x)=\int_x^4\sqrt{t^2+4}dt$, what is $F'(4)$ and $F^{\prime\prime}(4)$?

Tags: integration, limits, derivatives, definite-integrals

given $F(x)=\int_x^4\sqrt{t^2+4}dt$; now I know $'$ means we have to differentiate and so the integral and differentiation erases each other out. But I've know it's only applicable when we have $x$ as the upper limit. But in this case, we have $x$ as the lower limit, so do we just interchange the limits and put a negative value over in front the the statement and find the answer to $F'(4)= -\sqrt{20}$? or do we discard the fact that $x$ is in lower limit and just follow usual procedure and get the answer $F'(4)=\sqrt{20}$? I've having a little hard time trying to think about it intuitively.

Comment: You're right about needing the $-$ sign, so $F'(x)=-\sqrt{x^2+4}$. I leave you to differentiate again to obtain $F^{\prime\prime}$.

Answer (score 1):

This is a general formula for functions like $F(x)=\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}f(x,t)\mathrm{d}t$ with parameter $t$ in condition that $a(x),b(x)$ both differentiable, $f(x,t),\frac{\partial f(x,t)}{\partial x}$ both continuous:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}F(x)=\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}\frac{\partial f(x,t)}{\partial x}\mathrm{d}t+b'(x)f(x,b(x))-a'(x)f(x,a(x))
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular integration to integrate the function and use a minus sign like you did OR you can follow Leibnitz Theorem to directly get the value of $F'(x)$. Substituting $x=4$ will give the first derivative at $x=4$ and further differentiating $F'(x)$ obtained from Leibnitz will give the second derivative, i.e. $F''(x)$ and you can substitute $4$ to get the value of the second derivative at $x=4$.

Hope this is helpful.